# Passing data from input to vue's function

Tags: vue.js, parameter-passing

I want to pass data from an input:

```
<input
  id="txtName" 
  type="text"
  v-on:keyup.enter="addMessage(/* THIS FIELD VALUE */)"
/>
```

to a method:

```
methods: {
  addMessage(name) {
    //stuff
  }
}
```

I tried using `this` or `this.value` as a parameter but it is not working.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Solution 1: Using v-model(Preferred)**

HTML

```
<input id="txtName" @keyup.enter="addMessage" v-model="txtInput" type="text">
```

VueJS

```
data: {
    txtInput: ''
},
methods: {
    addMessage(){
      console.log(this.txtInput)
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: Using jQuery**

HTML

```
<input id="txtName" @keyup.enter="addMessage('txtName')" type="text">
```

import jQuery using `import $ from jquery`(webpack2 example)

VueJS

```
methods: {
    addMessage(id){
      console.log($('#txtName').val())
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution 1 made the best for me

Answer (score 30):

You could either use `v-model` to bind a data property to the input, and simply reference that in your method ([see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tkb70eh/2/)):

```
<input v-model="message" @keyup.enter="addMessage()"/>
```

```javascript
methods: {
  addMessage() {
    this.messages.push(this.message);
  }
}
```

Or, you can use the special inline `$event` property, which gives you a reference to the target element's value ([see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6w421snc/1/)):

```
<input @keyup.enter="addMessage($event)"/>
```

```
methods: {
  addMessage(e) {
    this.messages.push(e.target.value);
  }
}
```

---

You also don't need to explicitly pass the `$event` param to the `@` handler. You can just pass the handler the method name and the first argument will still be the value of `$event`.

Like so:

```
<input @keyup.enter="addMessage"/>
```

```
methods: {
  addMessage(e) { // e is the value of $event
    this.messages.push(e.target.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: My input only needed `@property="some_function($event)"` and to read it within the function `some_function(e) { console.log(e) }`. In this/my case, `e` was already the target value.

Answer (score 4):

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/zoqbz09j/)** is your example corrected to work. Just a couple of syntax errors, plus the handy fact that if you don't specify arguments in the onkeyup, you get the event, which is what you want.

### markup

```
<div id='ctr'>
  {{message}}
  <input  id="txtName" v-on:keyup.enter="addMessage" type="text">
</div>
```

### js

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el : '#ctr',
  data : {message: 'hello cobber'},
  methods: {
    addMessage: function(event){
      debugger;
      alert(event.target.value)
      //stuff
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example will help you -

```
<div class="form-register" :class="{ 'active': active == 'register' }" id="form-register">
        <div class="error-message" v-text="registerError"></div>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" v-model="registerName" @keyup.enter="submit('register', $event)" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" v-model="registerEmail" @keyup.enter="submit('register', $event)" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="registerPassword" @keyup.enter="submit('register', $event)" required>
        <input type="submit" :class="{ 'disabled': submitted == 'register' }" @click="submit('register', $event)" v-model="registerSubmit" id="registerSubmit">
        <div class="links"> <a href="" @click="flip('login', $event)">Already have an account?</a>

        </div>
      </div>
```

and in app.js

fetching data like this -

```
var modal_submit_register = 'Register';
var server = window.location.hostname;
var host = "http://"+server+"/";
//alert(host);

var modal = new Vue({
  el: '#login-modal',
  data: {
    active: null,
    submitted: null,

    // Submit button text
    registerSubmit: modal_submit_register,

    // Modal text fields
    registerName: '',
    registerEmail: '',
    registerPassword: '',
    loginUser: '',
    loginPassword: '',
    passwordEmail: '',

    // Modal error messages
    registerError: '',
    loginError: '',
    passwordError: '',
  },
  methods: {
    close: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.target === this.$el) {
        this.active = null;
      }
    },
    flip: function(which, e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (which !== this.active) {
        this.active = which;
      }
    },
    submit: function(which, e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.submitted = which
      var data = {
        form: which
      };

      switch (which) {

        case 'register':
          data.name = this.registerName;
          data.email = this.registerEmail;
          data.password = this.registerPassword;
          console.log(data);
          this.$set('registerSubmit', 'Registering...');

          $.ajax({
              url: 'register.php',
              method: 'POST',
              data: data,
              success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(){
                  console.log('We did not succeed!');
              }
          });
        break;



      }

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for this year and more elegant way:

```
<input id="txtName" type="text" v-on:keyup.enter="addMessage()"/>
```

in method:

```
methods: {
  addMessage({target}) {
    console.log(target.value);
  }
}
```

This will log input value.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Solution is:

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="text" v-model="inputMessage" />
```

I don't know why u want use it on keyup event but if u want do it, change `v-model` with `@keyup`, keyup is the short solution for `v-on:keyup` and on longtime better to use it so.

**app.js:**

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
    return {
        inputMessage: '',
    };
    },
    methods: {
    AddMessage() {
        this.inputMessage /*do something with it*/
    },
    },
});
```